# How do binary operators join queries?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have started using mongodb with C# and in examples of how to join multiple conditions of a query together they use binary operators.

I found the reference page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

But I am struggling to understand how the binary operator joins queries together for example:

```cs
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.A, "1");
filter &= (Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.B, "4") | Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.B, "5"));
filter = filter & Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.C, "7");
```

I have read the microsoft reference page and I just don't understand what exactly is going on when these binary operators are used.

Can someone explain what is actually happening that joins multiple queries into a single query?

Comment: C# has operator overloading.  [Bitwise And](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinition_1_op_BitwiseAnd.htm) and [BitwiseOr](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinition_1_op_BitwiseOr.htm) are operator methods; behind them is C# code that implements the join operations.

Comment: If you're curious about what the code looks like, you can find it [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/9dbfbaab20fcf6a1aeea72452d582fffb79e0cce/src/MongoDB.Driver/FilterDefinition.cs).

Comment: The only thing that is relevant to your line of code above in the article you linked [overloading binary operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#operator-overloadability) but [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) is probably better.  Otherwise you should take a look at the docs for the library you are using. I believe Robert provided that link.